# bash: how to make a triple check?

Tags: bash

I want check wither option user give to a script is one of the allowed. The best I figured out reading the manual is:

```
if [ $format = "flac" ] -o [ $format = "wav" ] -o [ $format = "ape" ]; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi
```

and it doesn't work. Perhaps it lacks some kind of a grouping.

Actually I made a logical mistake: to check wither option given is one of the: flac/wv/ape, one has to write

```
if ! [ $format = "flac" -o $format = "wv" -o $format = "ape" ]; then
```

So this solves it (Thaks to ziu). Another way to check the option is:

```
case $format in
    "flac");;
    "wv");;
    "ape");;
    *)
        usage
        exit 1
esac
```

This also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep everything in the same group:

```
if [ $format = "flac" -o $format = "wav" -o $format = "ape" ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
if [ $format = "flac" ] || [ $format = "wav" ] || [ $format = "ape" ]; then
     usage
     exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I wanted to check Your way, but since I've made a logical mistake - I actually needed `if ! [ $format = "flac" -o $format = "wv" -o $format = "ape" ]; then` - I can't see the way to check it. But thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
if [[ ! $format =~ "flac|wav|ape" ]]; then usage; exit 1; fi
```

EDIT: Logic was changed

Alternatively, you could do away with the `if` and use the `||` gate like so:

```
[[ $format =~ "flac|wav|ape" ]] || { usage; exit 1; }
```

Questions that return true look easier on the eye.

Comment: Doesn't work - I tried that. Have You taken into account that there has to be `if ! [ $format = "flac" -o $format = "wv" -o $format = "ape" ]; then` not `if [ $format = "flac" ] -o [ $format = "wav" ] -o [ $format = "ape" ]; then` - as I thought originally?
`